# Bayesian Networks

Tags: probability, bayesian-networks

I am working on following bayesian graph
   [Graph](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3BgGvY21W2jOXNNdmxvQ2JfbFU/edit?usp=sharing)

Here  I am trying to calculate probability of the following 
P(W,f)=?
I started as follow
P(w,f)=P(W/f).p(F)

**P(W/f)=P(W/R,S,f).P(R.S/F)+P(W/-R,s,f).P(-R.S/F)+P(W/R,-S,F).P(R.-S/F)+P(W/-R,-S,F).P(-R.-S/F)**
Since W is independent of F given R,S so
**P(W/f)=P(W/R,S).P(R.S/F)+P(W/-R,s).P(-R.S/F)+P(W/R,-S).P(R.-S/F)+P(W/-R,-S).P(-R.-S/F)**

Here next I don't know what is the probability of
P(R,s/F)???
Please any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't start like that. The method is:

1. Add in all other variables to get the full joint, e.g., just with S: P(W,F)=\sum_x P(W,F,S=x)
2. Simplify your full joint with conditional independences: P(W,F)=\sum_x P(F)P(W|S=x)P(S=x)

Add in all your variables, not just S.